# Atom package website not displaying image

Tags: html, atom-editor

I recently published my [first Atom Package](https://github.com/tobias-wilfert/tobias-wilfert-word-count). But when I checked my package page on [Atom.io](https://atom.io/packages/tobias-wilfert-word-count) I saw that the gif was not displayed, see below:

[image: Photo of photo not showing]

This struck me as odd as it is the default gif Atom provides. So I checked the source code of the website and found the following:

```html
<img src="https://i.github-camo.com/2c08678c355ef710338f4abf170cc999501b4093/68747470733a2f2f662e636c6f75642e6769746875622e636f6d2f6173736574732f36393136392f323239303235302f63333564383637612d613031372d313165332d383662652d6364376335626633666639622e676966" alt="A screenshot of your package" data-canonical-src="https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/69169/2290250/c35d867a-a017-11e3-86be-cd7c5bf3ff9b.gif">
```

I have no idea where the value for the `src` attribute of the `img` tag comes from.
However the actual link to the gif is still in the `img` tag but as `data-canonical-src`.
Funny enough the gif does display correctly when looking at the package in Atom itself:

[image: Photo of photo showing]

Does anyone know why this happens and/or how to avoid it?

Comment: The images for packages have been broken for a considerable time, so it's not your fault. See https://github.com/atom/atom/discussions/22904

Answer (score 0):

> The images for packages have been broken for a considerable time, so it's not your fault. See [github.com/atom/atom/discussions/22904](https://github.com/atom/atom/discussions/22904)

*-- [comment](/q/69691652/#comment123201944_69691652) by [idleberg](/users/1329116/idleberg)*